# How load a local html file with Chromium Embedded (CEF)?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded, delphi-10-seattle, cef4delphi

I want load a html file into **Chromium** ([CEF4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/CEF4Delphi)) but nothing is showed, only a white page.

Is possible load a local html file using the following approach?

[**Here**](https://pastebin.com/urzFfNzv) is html file.

Also have other trouble that is everytime that Chromium is executed, also is executed other instance of my application. How solve this?

Code used:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  FStarted: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function CEFApplication: TCefApplication;
var
  sPath: String;
begin
  sPath := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0));
  if not assigned(GlobalCEFApp) then
  begin
    GlobalCEFApp := TCefApplication.Create;
    GlobalCEFApp.FlashEnabled := False;
    GlobalCEFApp.FastUnload := True;

    GlobalCEFApp.FrameworkDirPath := sPath + 'cef';
    GlobalCEFApp.ResourcesDirPath := sPath + 'cef';
    GlobalCEFApp.LocalesDirPath := sPath + 'cef\locales';
    GlobalCEFApp.Cache := sPath + 'cef\cache';
    GlobalCEFApp.Cookies := sPath + 'cef\cookies';
    GlobalCEFApp.UserDataPath := sPath + 'cef\User Data';
    GlobalCEFApp.EnableGPU := False;
  end;
  if not FStarted then
    FStarted := GlobalCEFApp.StartMainProcess;

  result := GlobalCEFApp;
end;

initialization

CEFApplication;

end.
```

**Form2:**

```
procedure TForm2.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  while not(Chromium1.CreateBrowser(CEFWindowParent1, '')) and
    (Chromium1.Initialized) do
  begin
    Sleep(100);
    Application.processMessages;
  end;
  Chromium1.LoadURL(ExtractFilePath(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName)) + 'gmaps.html');
end;
```

---

**EDITION:**

Relative to my doubt about multiple instance of my application being executed, this is normal and right based on [**this**](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-processes)
article.

Comment: Use Chrome. Open the same local HTML file, and then look at the location bar. What does the filename look like there? Does it match the format of yours?

Comment: @KenWhite, is all correct (name of file and path).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do it in my code:

```
CBrowser.Load('file:///' + ReplaceStr(fpath, '\', '/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

CEF4Delphi has a `TChromium.LoadString` for that.

I do it in a protected

```
procedure BrowserCreatedMsg(var aMessage : TMessage); message CEF_AFTERCREATED;
```

like this:

```
procedure TDialoogDeclaratieGoogleMaps.BrowserCreatedMsg(var aMessage : TMessage);
begin
  PanelBrowser.UpdateSize;      // The TCEFWindowParent
  ChromiumBrowser.LoadString(FGoogleHTML);   // String read from file earlier
end;
```

and that message gets posted in the afterCreated method:

```
procedure TDialoogDeclaratieGoogleMaps.ChromiumBrowserAfterCreated(Sender: TObject; const browser: ICefBrowser);
begin
  PostMessage(Handle, CEF_AFTERCREATED, 0, 0);
end;
```